# Show that if $\sum_na_n=\infty$ and $a_n\downarrow 0$ then $\sum\limits_n\min(a_{n},\frac{1}{n})=\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $a_n$ be a sequence decreasing to $0$, and $\sum {{a_n} = \infty } $.
>   Show that:$$\sum {\min \left( {{a_n},{1 \over n}} \right)}  = \infty $$

If there's $N_0$ such that $\forall n>N_0: \min(a_n, {1\over n}) = {1\over n}$ 
or $\forall n>N_0: \min(a_n, {1\over n}) = a_n$ then, the problem is trivial.

Otherwise, let us define $b_n = \min(a_n, {1\over n})$ and two subsequences:
$$b_{n_k} = {1 \over n_k},\quad b_{n_l} = a_{n_l}$$

$$\sum {{b_n} = } \sum {{b_{{n_k}}}}  + \sum {{b_{{n_l}}}}  = \infty  + \infty $$

Is that right?

Comment: No, this is not right. Why must $\sum b_{n_k}=\infty$? Same for $\sum b_{n_l}$.

Comment: OK. Actually I thought about it and it is wrong :)

Comment: Note you have not used that $a_n$ decreases to $0$. The result is false otherwise.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225623/divergence-of-a-sequence

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a theorem (I believe called "Cauchy condensation test") that says that a series of positive decreasing terms $\sum_n s_n$ converges if and only if $\sum_k 2^k s_{2^k}$ converges. For your series you get that the series converges if and only if $\sum_k \min (2^k a_{2^k}, 1)$ converges. It is clear that this series converges if and only if $\sum_k 2^k a_{2^k}$ converges, which is if and only if $\sum_n a_n$ converges. So if $\sum_n a_n$ diverges then your series diverges.

Comment: Thanks, but why is it $1$? at $min(2^ka_{2^k}, 1)$?

Comment: No, it should be a $1$, as written. It is not a minor issue, it is key to make the proof work.

Comment: @AnnieOK I've rewritten one of the variables for clarity's sake (there was a namespace collision).  Consider that $s_n$ is your $b_n$, i.e., $s_n = \min(a_n, \frac1n)$.  Now, think about how you could write $2^ks_{2^k}$, given this definition of $s_n$.

Comment: @AnnieOK The $2^k$ term in your sequence is $\min(a_{2^k},1/2^k)$. So if you multiply that by $2^k$ for the Cauchy condensation test you get $\min(2^k a_{2^k},2^k/2^k) = \min(2^k a_{2^k}, 1)$.

Comment: @AnnieOK Do not forget to verify that the terms of this sequence are decreasing, so that you can indeed apply the test.

Comment: @AnnieOK it's $\sum_k 2^k a_{2^k}$ converges if and only if $\sum_n a_n$ converges (assuming $a_n$ is a positive decreasing sequence). Note the multiplying by $2^k$ in the first series.

Comment: @AnnieOK Hence you are able to show that $b_n=\min(a_n,\frac1n)$ defines a nonincreasing sequence $(b_n)$, right? By the way, how would you do that?

Comment: "It is clear that this series converges if and only if $\sum_k 2^k a_{2^k}$ converges". I don't think this is trivial.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the sequence $b_n:=\min(a_n,\frac{1}{n})$. Note that it is non-negative and **non-increasing**:
$$
0\leq b_{n+1}\leq a_n\quad\hbox{and}\quad 0\leq b_{n+1}\leq \frac1n.
$$ 
Thus, one can apply the [Cauchy condensation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) to prove the divergence of $\sum b_n$. Now, we want to show that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty2^n\min\left(a_{2^n},\frac1{2^n}\right)=\infty. 
$$
Consider the following two sets:
$$
A=\{n\in{\bf N}:a_{2^n}\geq\frac{1}{2^n}\},\quad B:=\{n\in{\bf N}:a_{2^n}<\frac{1}{2^n}\}. 
$$
If $A$ is infinite, then 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty2^n\min\left(a_{2^n},\frac1{2^n}\right)\geq \sum_{n\in A}1=\infty. 
$$
If $A$ is finite, then there exists some positive integer $k$, such that $n\in B$ for *all* $n\geq k$. It follows that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty2^n\min\left(a_{2^n},\frac1{2^n}\right)\geq \sum_{n=k}^\infty2^na_{2^n}=\infty
$$
where for the last equality we use the Cauchy condensation test and the fact that $\sum_{n=k}a^n=\infty$.

Comment: The accepted answer already mentions the Cauchy condensation test. Perhaps not as cleanly, though.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: Indeed. It was unclear for me in the [accepted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/739998/9464) that why "It is clear that this series converges if and only if $\sum_k 2^k a_{2^k}$ converges". I think it could be useful to write out the details how the theorem is applied. There is also another [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1334769/9464) using the Cauchy condensation test for the same problem in an unclear (I would say logically wrong) way.