# Looking for a counterexample for this statement regarding divergent series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples

I need counter for this statement :

> If the series $ \sum a_n$ is divergent then the series $b_n$= $\sum \text{min}(a_n,\frac{1}{n})$ is also divergent.

I closest I reached to a counter is ,
Define $a_n$ as $$a_n =  \begin{cases} \frac{1}{n²} \text{for n even} \\ \frac{1}{n} \text{(any divegrent series) for n odd} \end{cases} $$
Here, $\sum a_n$ is divergent. Because $\sum 1/n²$ is convergent but $\sum 1/n$ is not. So their sum is divergent.

Now, in $b_n$ At times when $n$ is even $a_n$ (is $\sum 1/n²$ will converge )  will be less than $1/n$ and could be a counter but at odd it will cause problem when because when $n$ is odd there will be $1/n$ equal to it and is divergent but i need it to converge.

If this statement is true then a proof is needed.

Kindly Help.

Thank You.

Comment: It’s hard to understand what your question is

Comment: Okay I'm editing it to make it more clear

Comment: Why do you think it’s false? It seems likely to be true, to me at least

Comment: This is a statement from a MCQ ,It also seemed true to me but this was incorrect (I too don't know how) ,now need a proof for it.

Comment: I see, yes you are right, the statement is false

Comment: It is true if $(a_n)$ is decreasing: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/739975/42969

Comment: Okay,  the thin is that if have "bad" $a_n$ we need to have "good" $\frac 1n < a_n$.  You have the idean that $\frac 1n^2$ are "good" so lets say If $n$ is a perfect square then $a_n$ is some term of a divergent sequence and $a_n = \frac 1{n^2}$ when $n$ is not a perfect square.  Then $\sum b_k = \sum_{k\text{ not a square}}\frac 1{k^2}+\sum \frac 1{k^2}$.

Comment: @fleablood that's a good approach for it, thank you sir.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Consider the sequence
$$
a_n =
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $n$ is not a power of $2$}\\
1 & \text{if $n$ is a power of $2$}.
\end{cases}
$$
Since there are infinitely many powers of $2$, $\sum a_n$ diverges.
However,
$$
b_n =
\min\left\{a_n,\frac{1}{n}\right\} =
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $n$ is not a power of $2$} \\
\frac{1}{n} & \text{if $n$ is a power of $2$}
\end{cases}
$$
satisfies that $\sum b_n$ converges.
Indeed,
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k} = 2.
$$

Comment: Note the reindexing in the last line.  The $b_n$ series represents all terms of the series, but the sum with k represents only the non zero terms of b.  Of course dropping out the zero terms  has no effect on the sum.  n vs k took me a minute or so to realize.

Comment: @nickalh Using proper English, the sum of all $b_n$'s is by definition the sum of all the inverse of the powers of $2$. No need to abstractly re-index. This is why I used words and not abstract notations to define $(a_n)$ and express $(b_n)$

Answer (score 2):

Just to mention that the statement in the OP holds if in addition is is assumed that $a_n\searrow0$. The proof of that can be obtained by Cauchy's condensation.

Notice the $a_n\searrow0$ implies that $\min(a_n,\frac1n)\searrow0$. If $\sum_n\min(a_n,\frac1n)<\infty$, $\sum_k2^k\min(a_{2^k},2^{-k})=\sum_k\min(2^ka_{2^k},1)<\infty$ and so, $\sum_k2^ka_{2^k}<\infty$ which in turn means that $\sum_na_n<\infty$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/739975/42969